# Session doesn't set , why?

Tags: php

I've this code:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $cislonak=$_GET['cislonakupu'];
     $_SESSION['cislonakupu'] = $cislonak;

    $sessionnakupu = $_SESSION['cislonakupu'];
    echo $sessionnakupu;
    ?>
```

Session works only on sites like: shoppingcart.php?cislonakupu=123456789       ...

On index.php it doesn't work.
Where is the problem?

Comment: It will only work if the variable `cislonakupu` is set. I presume index.php doesn't set that variable.

Comment: @ialarmedalien is here any way, how it could work without the variable $cislonakupu? (If session was already set)

Comment: Or maybe your $_GET variable is not set or empty...we'd need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['cislonakupu'])) {
  $cislonak = $_GET['cislonakupu'];
  $_SESSION['cislonakupu'] = $cislonak;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['cislonakupu'])) {
  $sessionnakupu = $_SESSION['cislonakupu'];
  echo $sessionnakupu;
}
?>
```